# Google Cloud Storage Transfer Service fails with UNKNOWN error

Tags: google-cloud-storage, file-transfer, google-cloud-platform

We've recently set up a transfer with Google Cloud Storage Transfer Service in order to archive less frequently used items in our Cloud Storage bucket to a bucket which uses Google Nearline.

The setup is very straightforward: transfer anything older than 24 in one bucket to another bucket. Both buckets are owned by the same Google Cloud Platform account.

Unfortunately every single transfer has failed so far. I read somewhere that having an invalid content type could cause this but all items in the bucket have the content type set to "application/octet-stream".

Any idea on how to solve this?

Here's the error we're getting.
[image: Here's the error we are getting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a permission issue.

You need to check the permission of the bucket and the objects inside the bucket.

Can you check the Logging tab to see if any more information appears?

Can you try to perform this operation using the gsutil tool and see what happens kind of error you get?

```
gsutil cp -c -L cp.log -r  gs://source-bucket/ gs://dest-bucket/
```

Comment: After contact with Google's support they confirmed that it was a permission issue. Their web site says: "grants a Cloud Storage Transfer Service account the necessary source, destination, and project permissions to complete the transfer." but that turned out to be incorrect. They've promised to update that text.