# BigQuery Data Transfer config cannot be saved, "unknown error"

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, file-transfer, data-transfer

I’m attempting to create a BigQuery Data Transfer config, however each time I try to save the config (after successfully going through the “Bigquery Data Transfer Service wants to access your Google Account” redirect), I get hit with a popup that say “Unable to save transfer configuration” and “Unknown error”. [Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fx2v.png).

The links that appear on the popup don’t provide any further explanation in resolving this issue. The dataset that I’m trying to save the data transfer is “aws-us-east-1” which is where the S3 bucket is located as well.

I followed the steps outlined in [GCP’s documentation for setting up an Amazon S3 data transfer](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/s3-transfer) so I’m at a loss currently.

My search attempts to find a similar issue uncovered t[his older issue with Google Cloud Storage Transfer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513937/google-cloud-storage-transfer-service-fails-with-unknown-error). That link suggests that the issue might be related to permissions, but my access key and secret for the S3 bucket are from my AdministratorAccess account and my GCP account has BigQuery admin.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem = I've solved it by creating a dataset not from "Data transfer" but from SQL workspace - it allows you to create US / EU multiple regions locations and with this dataset, all is working